# How To Show A Modal UIViewController On A Different Storyboard Using Segues?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have UIViewController A defined on Storyboard B.  UIViewController A frame dimensions are defined to be 470 wide and 100 high.

I want to segue to UIViewController A on Storyboard B from a UIButton on Storyboard A.

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ModalStoryboard"])
{
    NSLog(@"Show Modal UIViewController");
    RSStoryboardLink *storyboardLink = segue.destinationViewController;
    storyboardLink.setStoryboardName = @"ModalStoryboard";
    storyboardLink.setStoryboardScene = @"ModalStoryboard";
    storyboardLink.transitioningDelegate  = self;        
}
```

This segue is defined in IB to present modally (current context) and at a Preferred Explicit Size.  The segue works and the UIViewController is presented but it is always presented at full screen and not at the size it is defined as - 470 x 100 in IB.  It is not presented as a modal popover view.

How can I show a modal UIViewController on a different Storyboard using segues?